# Get number of objects into a merged queryset

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I've developed a Django's view that merge two queryset using`chain`; below the code.

```
def sharedcategories_list(request):
    list = SharedCategories.objects.all()
    context = {"list": list}
    return render(request, "shared-categories/shared_categories_list.html", context)


def single_sharedcategory(request, slug):
    object = get_object_or_404(SharedCategories, slug=slug)
    wms = OGCLayer.objects.filter(categories=object)
    webgis = WebGISProject.objects.filter(categories=object)

    context = {
        "single_object": object,
        "objects": list(chain(wms, webgis)),
    }
    template = "shared-categories/single_shared_categories.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The views use the models below:

```
class SharedCategories(CategoryBase):
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.UPLOADED_IMAGE_FOLDER, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single-sharedcategory", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


class OGCLayer(BaseModelPost, OpenLayersMapParameters):
    set_zindex = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    set_opacity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=1.0)
    ogc_layer_path = models.ForeignKey(GeoServerURL, related_name="related_geoserver_url", on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    ogc_layer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ogc_layer_style = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    ogc_bbox = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    ogc_centroid = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    ogc_legend = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_vector = models.BooleanField()
    is_raster = models.BooleanField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(SharedCategories, related_name="related_ogc_categories")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ogc-single", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


class WebGISProject(WebGISProjectBase):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(SharedCategories, related_name="related_webgisproject_categories")
    basemap1 = models.ForeignKey(Basemap, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="related_basemap1", blank=False, null=True)
    basemap2 = models.ForeignKey(Basemap, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="related_basemap2", blank=True, null=True)
    basemap3 = models.ForeignKey(Basemap, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="related_basemap3", blank=True, null=True)
    main_layer = models.ForeignKey(OGCLayer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="related_main_wmslayer")
    layers = models.ManyToManyField(OGCLayer, related_name="related_wmslayer", blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("map-single", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

I need to view in the template how many objects are related to `list`. I know that it is possible to get a count of objects for a single model with `{{ wms.related_ogc_categories.count }}`.
But how I can do the same thing in my case?

Below how I use `sharedcategories_list` into the template:

```
{% for item in list %}

  <div class="category-card">

    <div class="category-thumbnail">
      <img class="category-img" src="{{ item.icon.url }}" alt="{{ item.description }}">
    </div>
    <div class="category-info">
      <p>{{ item.title }} <br><span class="badge">{{ item|length }}</span></p>
    </div>

  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What about duplicates, if a OGCLayer is related to multiple SharedCategories do you want to count it just once or multiple times?

Comment: Multiple times because my aim is to see how many times a single object from `SharedCategories` is used.

Comment: Help me understand - is it true that you know what category you want to count, and you just want to count how many instances of `WebGISProject` and/or `OGCLayer` are related back to it?   Do you want to count the number of items in your chained list?  Just trying to understand to give a correct answer.

Comment: @sc_props I'm interested to know how many times is used a single item from `SharedCategories`. If one item from `SharedCategories` is used from both related models or only once from them or multiple time for both it is not a problem.

Comment: If your chained list is a proxy for how many times a given category is shared, you could do: `count = len(list(chain(wms, webgis)))`.  `len()` is a more expensive operation, but `.count()` won't work on chained querysets.  You could also count them both before chaining them.  I have a feeling this isn't a full answer for you, so let me know if that is the case.